# Line segment properly contained in convex set

Tags: convex-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

Let $K$ be a compact convex set in a locally convex space $X$. If $U$ is a convex set contained in $K$ which is open with respect to the subspace topology in $K$ does the following hold:

If $x\in U$ and $y\in \overline{U}\setminus U$ then $(1-t)x+ty\in U$ for $0\leq t<1$. Here the closure is taken with respect to the full space $X$.

If $x\in \mathrm{int}~U$ then I know that this is true, for instance this is stated in Proposition 1.11 in Chapter IV of *A course in Functional Analysis* by John B. Conway. However I don't know how to prove it otherwise and would appreciate help.

Comment: It says that $U$ is open, I would take that to mean every point of $U$ is an interior point of $U$. However, it says  "open with respect to the subspace topology in $K$" and I do not know/remember exactly what that means. If $U$ were not required to have an "open-type" property then you could get a counter-example by making $U$ a square that does not include the boundary except at one corner point. Then take $x$ as the included corner point and $y$ as a not-included corner point that shares an edge with $x$.

Comment: I believe that "the subspace topology" also known as the topology that $U$ "inherits" from $K$, is the family of sets that are intersections of $U$ with open sets in $K$. And the topology on $K$ is the one that it inherits from $X$ !

Comment: One could still perform your argument so the statement I gave is false

Answer (score 1):

I can modify Michaels argument to show that the statement is false. Let $K = [-1,1]\times [-1,1]$ which is a compact convex set and let $U = \Big((-1,1)\times(-1,1)\Big)\cup\Big((-\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2})\times\{1\} \Big)$. This set is open and convex in the subspace topology however take $y= (1,1)$ and $x =(0,1)$ then the open line segment between $(1,1)$ and $(0,1)$ is not contained in $U$.